# Create NavigationProperty in UI5 OData v4 model

Tags: odata, sapui5, odata-v4

**Dear UI5-experts!**

I am facing a binding-issue with OData v4 model. I have a simple OData-structure with Persons being assigned to a Department, see extract from metadata.xml:

```
... 
<EntityType Name="Person">
        <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int64"/>
        <Property Name="FirstName" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="LastName" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="Email" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="Mobile" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="Username" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <NavigationProperty Name="Department" Type="OData.WTS.Department" Partner="Person"/>
</EntityType>

<EntityType Name="Department">
        <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int64"/>
        <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <NavigationProperty Name="Person" Type="OData.WTS.Person" Partner="Department"/>
</EntityType>
...
```

Now I want to build a UI5-app that lets users create new persons which should be assigned to a department (which should be selected via ValueHelp). Therefore I created a list-page which has its items bound to the model:

```
<Table items="{ path: 'userService>/Persons', parameters : {$expand: 'Department'} }">
    ...
</Table>
```

The department itself is bound in an XML-view:

```
...
<form:FormElement>
    <form:label>
        <Label text="{i18n>User.Department}"/>
    </form:label>
    <form:fields>
        <Input id="Department"
               name="{userService>Department/Id}"
               value="{userService>Department/Name}"
               showValueHelp="true" valueHelpOnly="true"
               valueHelpRequest="onValueHelpRequestDepartment" />
    </form:fields>
</form:FormElement>
...
```

When the user presses on a "New Person" button, I create a new transient model-entry via OData v4 ListBindingContext:

```
oListBindingContext
    .create({
            Id: null,
            Username: "",
            FirstName: "",
            LastName: "",
            Email: "",
            Mobile: "",
            Department: {
                Id : null,
                Name : null
            }
        }, function (oError) {
            // handle error
        }
    );
```

When the user now selects a department via ValueHelp, I want to assign it's Id and Name the the newly created Person's department Id and Name. I try to do this via the Input-control's setter-functions, as the properties are bound to the department:

```
// this should update the model-value
var oInput = this.getView().byId("Department");
oInput.setName(sSelectedId);
oInput.setValue(oSelectedBindingContext.getProperty("Name"));
```

But this leads to an exception:

```
Failed to update path /Persons/-1/Department/Name - Error: /Persons/-1/Department/Name: No key predicate known at /Persons/-1/Department
    at error (http://localhost/ui5resources/sap/ui/model/odata/v4/ODataMetaModel-dbg.js?eval:1189:10)
    at eval (http://localhost/ui5resources/sap/ui/model/odata/v4/ODataMetaModel-dbg.js?eval:1297:7)
    at new SyncPromise (http://localhost/ui5resources/sap/ui/model/odata/v4/lib/_SyncPromise-dbg.js?eval:72:15)
    at SyncPromise.then (http://localhost/ui5resources/sap/ui/model/odata/v4/lib/_SyncPromise-dbg.js?eval:151:12)
    at eval (http://localhost/ui5resources/sap/ui/model/odata/v4/ODataMetaModel-dbg.js?eval:1288:47)
```

Do you have any hints how to implement this simple scenario with OData v4? Am I misunderstanding the OData v4-concepts in here? Im am using OpenUI5 version 1.50.6.

Thanks in advance :-)
Mirco

Comment: Either you are passig a wrong key '-1' from UI or please check your odata entityset, if you have maked any attribute as a key or not?

Answer (score 0):

[ODataListBinding#methods/create](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding#methods/create)

Note: A deep create is not supported. The dependent entity has to be created using a second list binding. Note that it is not supported to bind relative to a transient context